# How to set default record source?

Tags: linux, audio, kde, pulse-audio

I am working in Centos 7. I've created null-source and set up as a default source with pacmd set-default-source. However, whenever I try to record from some applications, they start to use different source. It follows the order of 'Default Audio Recording Device Preferences' from Audio Setup -> Audio Recording. Why set-default-source doesn't change this order? Is there a way to automate process of changing order or maybe it is necessary to open KDE Control Module?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem dealing with my Bluetooth Headset and its two modes of operation (high quality vs call/microphone).

I'm just looping through all source-outputs and moving them one by one.

Here's my code, hope it helps put you in the right path. Take care.

```
function move_all {
  sink=$1 # define your destination sink here

  pacmd list-source-outputs | grep index | while read line
  do
    index=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d' ')
    # Ignore errors because some sources are "DONT_MOVE" (what I think means, not being used)
    #                                     vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    pacmd move-source-output $index $sink 2>&1 >/dev/null
  done
}
```

[source](https://github.com/gunar/dotfiles/blob/3d70a4c6c592221c4ff3c46b6106d8b402a76da8/scripts/blueswitch.sh#L15-L27)